# Confusion about using prepositions

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Here I have two sentences:

1. It was my first trip_____Hawaii.
2. I was late____school.

I'm sure the first sentence has preposition **to**.
I think the second sentence also has the preposition **to**, but it is wrong. Instead of **to**, **for** is the correct one. Why can't I to use **to** instead of **for**? Both sentences refer to place only. Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the preposition **to** in the first sentence to show **movement**

The **movement** refers to you going to Hawaii.

In the second sentence we use **for** to show a **purpose.**

The purpose is to go to school i.e. I was late for the purpose of going to school and not for any other reason.

Answer (score 2):

I am a native American speaker, and both choices seem natural to me. Both are common in speaking and writing, but [according to Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=late%20for%20school%2Clate%20to%20school&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clate%20for%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clate%20to%20school%3B%2Cc0) (both British and American English) "to be late for" is more common overall, especially in writing. However, in British English, "late to school" is [much less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=late%20for%20school%2Clate%20to%20school&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clate%20for%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blate%20for%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLate%20for%20school%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clate%20to%20school%3B%2Cc0), which is likely why it was considered wrong.